# Split a query into N results based on X number of words in query

Tags: google-sheets

I'm working on a spreadsheet to help simplify job searches within the game industry. I have a list of 785 game-related domains, which I would like to search for keywords via Google, in groups.

Google limits queries to 32 words. A domain (like `badrobot.com`) is considered one word, and operator words don't count towards the limit. Since I want to use search keywords in addition to multiple domains, I need to:

- count the number of keywords listed in the sheet
- subtract `n` number of words from the available cap (32)
- grab `n` domains from the list
- output a concatenated query string for the user, which merges the domains and the keywords.
- repeat output until all domains have been offered in query strings.

I have succeeded in writing a query that dynamically selects `n` rows based on the wordcount, but I'm stumped by how to iterate this query output for the entire domain list.

*[EDIT: thanks for the feedback @Tedinoz! Additional info following this comment]*

Sample data, details following:

```
| UNIQUE DOMAINS (765)   | JOB TITLES (21 WORDS)  | ADD'L SEARCH TERMS (1 WORDS) | CAP |
|------------------------|------------------------|------------------------------|-----|
| 8circuitstudios.com    | production coordinator | junior                       | 10  |
| acemaddox.com          | producer               |                              |     |
| adhocla.com            | associate producer     |                              |     |
| alderongames.com       | project manager        |                              |     |
| alkimiainteractive.com | support technician     |                              |     |
| antstream.com          | technical support      |                              |     |
| apocalypse333.com      | operations specialist  |                              |     |
| apply.workable.com     | operations coordinator |                              |     |
| artificialrome.com     | project manager        |                              |     |
| aweinteractive.com     | project specialist     |                              |     |
| awem.com               | operations associate   |                              |     |
| [...]                  |                        |                              |     |
```

Expected single-query output, correctly grabbing the first 8 domains (again, counted as 1 word each), and then the 22 search words:

`(site:8circuitstudios.com OR site:acemaddox.com OR site:adhocla.com OR site:alderongames.com OR site:alkimiainteractive.com OR site:antstream.com OR site:apocalypse333.com OR site:apply.workable.com OR site:artificialrome.com) (production coordinator OR production manager OR producer OR associate producer OR support technician OR technical support OR operations specialist OR operations coordinator OR project manager OR project specialist OR operations associate) (junior)`

This query was generated using this formula:

`=concatenate("(site:" & textjoin(" OR site:", 1, INDIRECT("$A"&2&":A"&D2)) & ")" & " (" & textjoin(" OR ", 1, $B$2:$C) & ")" & " (" & textjoin(" OR ", 1, $C$2:$C) & ")")`

To iterate through the remaining 757 domains, the formula should output another 59 queries just like this one, which the user can manually visit at their leisure.

But without a `for` or `while` function in Sheets, I'm a bit lost how to begin attacking this. Is `arrayformula` the key here? I'm having a hard time grasping exactly how it works.

Spreadsheet is [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1fMa4dg1mERF-NJD3uTxxmQKPC7voEpn223c_c9cHda8/edit?usp=sharing) for the curious.

Much appreciate any advice you can give!

Comment: `Spreadsheet is here with comments in red:` Your question needs to stand on its own. Please do not assume that users can/should/will/must open your spreadsheet to better understand your data and/or your question. Your data should be included in the body of your question. Would you please edit your question to include sample data AND example(s) of successful outcomes as a text tables. There are many ways to create a table including an online free service at [www.tablesgenerator.com](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables). Would you also include your query.

Comment: `grabbing the first 8 domains` FWIW, your sample is extracting 9 (nine) domains.

Comment: Have you considered using a helper column consisting of a sequence of (row numbers+8) that can be used in the indirect formula to identify the start row and the end row (end row = start row+8-1).

Comment: I hadn't thought of that method specifically, but that's a good idea. My idea had been to use a multiplier integer based on how many rows it needs to pick up (`rows`*2, *3, etc) but a helper column would work the same. That still would require some form of interation though, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

don't know if it's the best solution but the result seems to be OK.

```
=query({map(A2:A45,lambda(value,if(mod(row(value),10)=2,"(site:"&textjoin(" OR site:",1,indirect("A"&row(value)&":A"&row(value)+9))&") ("&textjoin(" OR ",1,B2:B)&") ("&textjoin(" OR ",1,C2:C)&")",
"no formula")))},"SELECT Col1 WHERE Col1<>'no formula'")
```

I used domains from A2 to A45 but you can extend this to your need.

Antoine

Comment: Exceptional. This does exactly what I need. A thousand thanks!

Comment: just FYI, your formula worked a treat and the team is loving the tool. Thanks again for your help!!